# How to bypass the necessary refresh after going to previous page when form is posted?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a page in wich you can fill in numerous things in a HTML form, after this the user can submit the form.

If the form is submitted I use a query to retrieve things from the database with the data the user filled in. A search page.
The user can click on search results and gets redirected to the info page of one result.

When the user goes to the previous page it says I need to confirm form resubmission.
How do I accomplish that this message is not shown when using the back button?

It does not matter if the search results are or arent availabe when going back.

What is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: Post/redirect/Get, Google it.

Comment: Or you can just have the form's method set to "get" (instead of "post" which I'm guessing is what you have it set to now)

Comment: Also, GET is better than POST for search results because it makes it possible for the search result to be bookmarked or for a link to it to be shared.